# Dont know what i did wrong php login script

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

As instructed i have to insert the code inbetween the dashed lines.
Supposed to refresh and see 'exists'
I have the correct database, table, everything im pretty sure but
i see no exist.
Should i keep following the guide or did i mess up?

Does anyone have a guide that is GUARANTEED to work if i follow it correctly?

my login.php

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

-----------------------------------------
if (user_exists('alex') === true) {
echo "exists";
}
die('no exist');
-------------------------------------------
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password';
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'We can not find that user';
    }
}
    ?>
```

i have init.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

$errors = array();
?>
```

i have users.php

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = '$username'");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>

i have general.php
<?php
function sanitize($data) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}
?>
```

i use:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
```

note: if anyone is familiar with phpacademy i am following his guide

Comment: What's the error You are gettin'?

Comment: Then why did the guy say im supposed to see 'exists' lol

Comment: How is this question related to phpmyadmin?  And have you verified that your `users` table really does have a row with the username `"alex"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `die` is always called, you should change your code to:

```
if (user_exists('alex') === true) {
    echo "exists";
}
else{
   die('no exist');
}
```

Comment: I believe that code is just there for testing.  The OP needs to clarify, of course.